# Does JSF (and JSF components) makes sense in a HTML5 World?

Tags: java, html, jsf

Since most of HTML5 is about client-side components and client-side JS logic, does it make sense to use JSF with HTML5? It seems to me that most of the "features" JSF (as a view technology) provides overlap with HTML5 ones (rich components, lifecycle, ajax). In other words, what benefits would I gain in using JSF instead of a simpler pure-servlet (or SpringMVC, or something RESTful, etc.) backend?

By the way, what do you suggest as a Java backend framework for HTML5 apps?

Comment: How is "what benefits would I gain in using JSF instead of a simpler pure-servlet (or SpringMVC, or something RESTful, etc.) backend?" not construtive? Just because someone answered in a bad way (which by the way did not answer my question) doesn't mean my question is bad. And as @BalusC points out in the comment, JSF is a component based MVC framework so much as (in my understanding) is HTML5. Except one is half-client and half-server side and the other is completely client side. So again, is there any benefits in using both or I'm wrong in my understanding?